# The distribution of the linear combination of Gamma random variables

Tags: distributions

If $X_i\sim\Gamma(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq n$, let 
$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n c_iX_i$ where $c_i$ are positive real numbers.
Assume all the parameters $\alpha_i$'s and $\beta_i$'s are all known, what is $Y$'s distribution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Theorem 1 given in [Moschopoulos](http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/037_3_0541.pdf) (1985) for the distribution of a sum of independent gamma variables.  You can extend this result using the [scaling property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Scaling) for linear combinations.

Comment: According to reference, the distribution function is: $g(y) = C\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\delta_k y^{\rho+k-1}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta_1}}}{\Gamma(\rho+k)\beta_i^{\rho+k}} $

Comment: where $C = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_i}\right)^{\alpha_i}$

Comment: And $\gamma_k = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\frac{(1 - \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_i})^k}{k}$

Comment: with
$\rho = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i$

Comment: And finally 
$\delta_k = \frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\gamma_i\delta_{k+1-i}; \delta_0=1, k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$

Comment: @Gong-Yi: nice, thanks for updating with the answer!

Comment: Actually, for N=2, this result can be simplified, where the summation after C is finite.

Comment: @Tina Welcome to the site; but please don't use answers for comments. Please read the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @Gong-YiLiao I think the formula for $\delta_k$ is actually for $\delta_{k+1}$, according to Eq 2.8 in the paper.