# Distribution of the ratio of dependent magnitude square of complex Gaussians

Tags: probability, distributions

Assume that $X=X_1 + X_2 +...+X_n$, where $X_i \sim CN(0,\sigma^2)$ and independent. Here $CN$ means circular complex Gaussian.

The question is, what is the distribution for

$Z = \frac{\left|X\right|^2}{\left|X_1\right|^2 + \left|X_2\right|^2+...+\left|X_n\right|^2}$

How can we benefit from the results obtained here: 
[Distribution of the ratio of dependent chi-square random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88628/distribution-of-the-ratio-of-dependent-chi-square-random-variables)

Comment: Is this question from a course or a textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung. No, this question is not from any class.