# What's the distribution of this random variable, and why?

Tags: gamma-distribution, ratio

Suppose $S_x\sim\Gamma(n,\theta)$,$S_y\sim\Gamma(m,\theta)$, $S_x$ and $S_y$ are independent. What's the distribution of $T=\frac{S_x}{S_x+S_y}$?

Comment: Hint: You can find an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/200639/11887

Comment: You can also simply look at the "related distributions" section of the wikipedia page on the gamma distribution for the same answer.  ... Is this coursework?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88628 is a special case.  When $n$ and $m$ are integral, the method described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252692 gives a solution.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks! That's very helpful.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks! It's very helpful!

Comment: @whuber Thanks! Yes, m and n are integers.