# Distribution of the ratio of dependent non-central chi-square random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, beta-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, ratio, distribution-identification

I am working on a problem that is similar to the one discussed in this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88628/distribution-of-the-ratio-of-dependent-chi-square-random-variables). But in my case $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(1, \sigma^2)$, i.e., $X_i$ is not a zero-mean Gaussian RV. Specifically, I want to find the distribution of $Z = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^L X_i\right)^2} {L \sum_{i=1}^L X_i^2}$, where $L$ in my case is 11. I found the numerator is $\sim$ $\chi_1^{'^2}(L)$ and the denominator is $\sim$ $\chi_L^{'^2}(\frac{L}{\sigma^2})$; where $\chi_k^{'^2}(\lambda)$ denotes the [non-central chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution). I am unable to proceed beyond this point. monte-carlo simulation of the R.V. Z results in the following CDF plot: [image]

As seen from the simulation, the value of the RV will lie between 0 and 1. The value that Z takes in my problem is a threshold between 0 and 1. Knowing the distribution (a closed-form equation) will help me determine other parameters like detection, false alarm, miss-detection probability etc.

Can someone kindly help how I can proceed. Is there a closed-form solution when $X_i$ is a non-zero mean Gaussian r.v.. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that you're using "amplitude ratio" units for the values of $\sigma$ as $\sigma=0$dB seems to mean $\sigma=1$.  If so please clarify that.  Also what are your definitions of "parameters like detection, false alarm, miss-detection probability, etc."  Given the 16 values of $\sigma$ and the simulations, you could fit a function of $\sigma$ for all of those parameters.

Comment: Yes, $\sigma$ is in dB. For linear, $\sigma_{linear} = 10^{\frac{\sigma_{dB}}{10}}$. For e.g., prob of false detection will be the CCDF, P(Z1 > r) and prob of miss detection will be the CDF, P(Z2 < r). Z1 and Z2 are r.v. (defined as Z in the problem) observed at time t1 and t2. At t1, the signal is absent and ratio r determines the false detection rate. At t2, signal is present and ratio r determines the miss detection rate. Yes, I think I can fit a function for $\sigma$. Was wondering if there is a closed-form solution for this r.v.

Comment: If the moments of this distribution are enough, this other post may be useful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605979/expected-value-of-rayleigh-quotient-non-centered-gaussian-vector/606658#606658

Answer (score 3):

I think that the article ["Evaluating the density of ratios of noncentral quadratic forms in normal variables"](https://%20https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947308005070) may be what you are looking for, although there doesn't seem to be a nice tidy expression there.

In Proposition 1 in the paper, it gives the density for $R=\frac{X'AX}{X'BX}$ where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, I)$ and *B* is positive semi-definite. You need to use matrix $A$ with 1's in the diagonal and $\frac{1}{2}$ elsewhere, and $B=\mathbf{I}L$ in that formula, and you should get the desired density.

The formula given in the paper is quite complicated, but maybe it will simplify out when you substitute in the matrices $A$ and $B$ associated with your problem (that's what happened to me in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605559/expected-value-of-the-outer-product-of-normalized-non-centered-gaussian-vector/606660#606660) similar problem).

For completeness, the formulas in the paper are:

[image: Extracted from S.Broad, M.S Paolella 2009]

As a note, if what you want are the moments of the ratio, and not the density per se, then there are nicer formulas and approximations. In this other [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605979/expected-value-of-rayleigh-quotient-non-centered-gaussian-vector/606658#606658), I show an exact analytic formula for the first moment of quadratic forms of this type. To adapt it to your specific problem you'd just need to scale X so that instead of having L in the denominator, you have 1/L in the numerator, and do that in matrix form.

**Edit:** The previous version of this answer had a wrong matrix $A$, that didn't match the ratio in the question.