# Distribution of $x_4(x_1-x_3)+x_5(x_2-x_1)$ with iid $x_i \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable

**Problem**

Given are 5 independent standard normal variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$.

What is the pdf of $x_4(x_1-x_3)+x_5(x_2-x_1)$ ?

**What I know**

$$x_1-x_3\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sqrt{2}\right)\tag{1}$$
$$x_2-x_1\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sqrt{2}\right)\tag{2}$$
$$x_4(x_1-x_3)\sim \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{2}}K_0\left(\frac{\left|z\right|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\tag{3}$$
$$x_5(x_2-x_1)\sim \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{2}}K_0\left(\frac{\left|z\right|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\tag{4}$$

where $K_0$ is the Bessel function and eq.(3,4) is a [normal product distribution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html).
Remains to add the 2 summands $x_4(x_1-x_3)$ and $x_5(x_2-x_1)$ but they are dependent and cannot be convolved.

**Related problem from literature**

If two variables are transformed like $x_1(a x_1+b x_2)$ with $a\in \mathbb{R},b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ then the pdf is known $[1]$ but this is not applicable here.

**Simulation**

Simulation shows that the distribution of $x_4(x_1-x_3)+x_5(x_2-x_1)$ can be approximated with a Laplace distribution with parameter $(0,1.34)$. But the сorrect answer is not a Laplace distribution.

---

$[1]$ R. Gaunt: A note on the distribution of the product of zero-mean correlated normal random variables, Statistica Neerlandica, 2018

Comment: why would you consider this r.v.?

Comment: why do you consider the function of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_5$ as you asked?

Comment: as it is a part of a problem

Comment: there is a theorem which gives us a way to get the law of $y=f(x_1,...,x_n)$ know each $x_i$ distribution unfortunely I was not told what this theorem is called for. That envolves jacobian matrix inverting functions and stuff.

Comment: The pdf would be $f(z) = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^5} \delta_{g(x) = z} \mathcal{N}(x;0,I_5)$ where $g(x) = x_4(x_1 - x_3) + x_5(x_2 - x_1)$ but I don't know if the integral can be solved.

Comment: You can rewrite the expression as $qr+rs+st+tu$, where $q=-x_3$, $r=x_4$, $s=x_1$, $t=-x_5$, $u=-x_2$, and again $q,r,s,t,u$ are all iid normals. This makes it clear that the expression links all the variables, so you can’t determine its distribution by breaking it down into independent pieces.

Comment: @Matt F.: Not so.  Linear algebra comes to the rescue here, because this expression is a symmetric quadratic form (albeit not a definite one).  Specifically, it can be expressed as $$2(x_4(x_1-x_3)+x_5(x_2-x_1)) =(x_2-x_3+x_4+x_5)^2/4-(-x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5)^2/4+\sqrt{3}(-\sqrt{1/3}x_1+\sqrt{1/12}(x_2+x_3)+(1/2)(-x_4+x_5))^2-\sqrt{3}(-\sqrt{1/3}x_1+\sqrt{1/12}(x_2+x_3)+(1/2)(x_4-x_5))^2.$$ The four squared terms are uncorrelated, whence independent, thereby exhibiting this as a [linear combination of Gamma variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/919).

Comment: @whuber : ".. are uncorrelated, whence independent ", can you please substantiate this statement ?

Comment: @GCab That's a basic property of Normal distributions. The shortest demonstration adds the cumulant generating functions and observes the result is that of a Normal distribution.

Comment: @whuber, right for Normal variate, but each addendum is a Chi-square .. still valid uncorrelation -> independence ?

Comment: @GCab When $(X,Y)$ is independent and $f, g$ are measurable functions, then $(f(X), g(Y))$ is independent.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872 for one demonstration.  Intuitively (restricting to continuous random variables), if you can find a separable expression for the density of $(X,Y),$ it remains separable for $(f(X),g(Y))$ too (which is obvious).

Comment: @whuber: I see .. apart from squaring, you mean that the four vectors $(x_2-x_3+x_4+x_5)$ etc. are orthogonal to each other ?

Comment: @GCab Yes.  I see my phrase "four squared terms are uncorrelated" was ambiguous: the *terms,* not their squares, are the ones that are obviously uncorrelated.

Comment: @whuber  which in fact they are, and so they represent four Normal v. which are actually independent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Linear algebra shows

$$2(x_4(x_1-x_3)+x_5(x_2-x_1)) =(x_2-x_3+x_4+x_5)^2/4-(-x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5)^2/4+\sqrt{3}(-\sqrt{1/3}x_1+\sqrt{1/12}(x_2+x_3)+(1/2)(-x_4+x_5))^2-\sqrt{3}(-\sqrt{1/3}x_1+\sqrt{1/12}(x_2+x_3)+(1/2)(x_4-x_5))^2.$$

Each squared term is a linear combination of independent standard Normal variables scaled to have a variance of $1,$ whence each of those squares has a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution.  The four linear combinations are also orthogonal (as a quick check confirms), whence uncorrelated; and because they are uncorrelated joint random variables, they are *independent.*

> Thus, the distribution is that of (a) half the difference of two *iid* $\chi^2(1)$ variables *plus* (b) $\sqrt{3}$ times half the difference of independent *iid* $\chi^2(1)$ variables.

(Differences of *iid* $\chi^2(1)$ variables have Laplace distributions, so this equivalently is the sum of two independent Laplace distributions of different variances.)

Because the characteristic function of a $\chi^2(1)$ variable is

$$\psi(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2it}},$$

the characteristic function of this distribution is

$$\psi(t/2) \psi(-t/2) \psi(t\sqrt{3}/2) \psi(-t\sqrt{3}/2) = \left[(1+t^2)(1+3t^2)\right]^{-1/2}.$$

This is not the characteristic function of any Laplace variable -- nor is it recognizable as the c.f. of any standard statistical distribution.  I have been unable to find a closed form for its inverse Fourier transform, which would be proportional to the pdf.

Here is a plot of the formula (in red) superimposed on an estimate of $\psi$ based on a sample of 10,000 values (real part in black, imaginary part in gray dots):

[image: Figure]

The agreement is excellent.

---

#### Edit

**There remain questions of what the PDF $f$ looks like.**  It can be computed by numerically inverting the Fourier Transform by computing

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-i x t} \psi(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{e^{-i x t}}{\sqrt{(1+t^2)(1+3t^2)}}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

This expression, by the way, fully answers the original question.  The aim of the rest of this section is to show it is a practical answer.

Numerical integration will become problematic once $|x|$ exceeds $10$ or $15,$ but with a little patience can be accurately computed.

In light of the analysis of differences of Gamma variables at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/919, **it is tempting to approximate the result** by a mixture of the two Laplace distributions.  The best approximation near the middle of the distribution is approximately $0.4$ times Laplace$(1)$ plus $0.6$ times Laplace$(\sqrt{3}).$  However, the tails of this approximation are a little too heavy.

[image: Figure]

The left hand plot in this figure is a histogram of 100,000 realizations of $x_4(x_1-x_3) + x_5(x_2-x_1).$  On it are superimposed (in black) the numerical calculation of $f$ and then, in red, its mixture approximation.  The approximation is so good it coincides with $f.$  However, it's not perfect, as the related plot at right shows.  This plots $f$ and its approximation on a logarithmic scale.  The decreasing accuracy of the approximation in the tails is clear.

Here is an `R` function for computing values of a PDF that is specified by its characteristic function.  It will work for any numerically well-behaved CF (especially one that decays rapidly).

```R
cf <- Vectorize(function(x, psi, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, ...) {
  g <- function(y) Re(psi(y) * exp(-1i * x * y)) / (2 * pi)
  integrate(g, lower, upper, ...)$value
}, "x")
```

As an example of its use, here is how the black graphs in the figure were computed.

```R
f <- function(t) ((1 + t^2) * (1 + 3*t^2)) ^ (-1/2)
x <- seq(0, 15), length.out=101)
y <- cf(x, f, rel.tol=1e-12, abs.tol=1e-14, stop.on.error=FALSE, subdivisions=2e3)
```

The graph is constructed by connecting all these $(x,y)$ values.

This calculation for $101$ values of $|x|$ between $0$ and $15$ takes about one second.  It is massively parallelizable.

For more accuracy, increase the `subdivisions` argument--but expect the computation time to increase proportionally.  (The figure used `subdivisions=1e4`.)

Comment: excellent work, I particularly appreciate the reduction to i.i.d. variables

Comment: The PDF then can only expressed as an integral?

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather straightforward to use the formula for the convolution of the two Laplace distributions?

Comment: @user277126 Yes.  Please feel free to do so.  I would like to see what answer you get for the pdf ;-).  Granular: I won't claim it can *only* be expressed as an integral, but the indications are that any other expression will either be more complicated (*e.g.,* infinite series expansions) or will involve other transcendental functions that are ultimately defined by similar integrals.  This particular integral is a very nice one.  For instance, it makes it easy to compute positive integral moments of the distribution. You can also numerically compute its FT to graph the PDF.

Comment: When I derive the PDF in the way I mentioned, I obtain a result that agrees with the general result given in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100746/difference-between-two-i-i-d-laplace-distributions? by is.magl in a comment.  But when I simulate the random variables, the density does not agree.  In this case the PDF would be \begin{eqnarray*} f_Z{z} = -\frac{1}{4}\exp \left(-|z| \right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\exp \left(-\left|z/ \sqrt{3} \right| \right). \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @user277126 The linked thread concerns the difference of two *identically distributed* Laplace variables.  That is easy to compute using, for instance, the partial fractions method I describe at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/919.  When the spreads of those variables differ, though (as in the present case), that method no longer works--nor does the direct convolution you refer to work out, either. You have written down the PDF for a *mixture* of variables rather than their *sum.*

Comment: Hmm I see, I will have to check where the mistake is made in the math then

Comment: @user277126 Your mixture representation is a remarkably good approximation.  In an edit to this post I briefly analyze a similar mixture approximation.

Comment: @whuber I am confused by the statement: "The four linear combinations are also orthogonal (as a quick check confirms), whence uncorrelated". Orthogonal does not automatically imply uncorrelated (see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254330622_Linearly_Independent_Orthogonal_and_Uncorrelated_Variables). How do understand your sentence?

Comment: @user Although you are correct generally, in the case where variables are multivariate normally distributed, uncorrelated *does* imply independent.  One proof examines the characteristic function: uncorrelated implies the characteristic function factors into a product of marginal characteristic functions, which is equivalent to independent.  That is why I took care to specify these variables have *Normal* distributions at the outset: that's critical.

Answer (score 1):

An almost exact expression could be derived using link between $\chi^{2}$, $\Gamma$ and symmetric $VG$ variance gamma distributions. Given very useful results above by @whuber, we can proceed first by the link $\chi^{2}(1)\sim\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},2)$. Therefore, from result that the product in question is distributed as $\frac{1}{2}[X_{1}-X_{2}]+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}[Y_{1}-Y_{2}]$ and knowing that $X_{1,2}\sim\chi^{2}(1)$, $Y_{1,2}\sim\chi^{2}(1)$ and $\chi^{2}(1)\sim\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},2)$. We will have,
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}[X_{1}-X_{2}]+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}[Y_{1}-Y_{2}]\sim\left[\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},1)-\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},1)+\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\sqrt{3})-\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\sqrt{3})\right]
\end{equation}$$
which is the sum of difference of $\Gamma(\alpha,\nu)$ rvs. Now, symmmetric $VG$, which was introduced by Madan and Seneta (1990) is a distribution with $\sigma W\sqrt{\Gamma(\alpha_{G},\nu_{G})}$ where $W\sim N(0,1)$ and could be written as a difference of two $\Gamma$ distributed rvs. This has a characteristic function (CF)
$$\begin{equation}
\phi(u,\sigma,\nu)=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\nu u^{2}\sigma^{2}}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\nu}}
\end{equation}$$
Difference of $\Gamma(\alpha,\nu)$ rvs will have CF
$$\begin{equation}
\phi(u,\alpha,\nu_{G})=\left(\frac{1}{1+\nu_{G}^{2}}\right)^{\alpha}
\end{equation}$$
Equating these two will give us
$$\begin{equation}
\sigma=\nu_{G}\sqrt{2\alpha}\\
\nu=\frac{1}{\alpha}
\end{equation}$$
Therefore, $\frac{1}{2}[X_{1}-X_{2}]+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}[Y_{1}-Y_{2}] \sim VG(\sigma=1,\nu=2)+VG(\sigma=\sqrt{3},\nu=2)$. Here we have some result, but still we need the convolution of these two $VG$ random variables. There is following convolution rule for $VG$ distribution, $VG(\sigma_{1},\nu_{1})+VG(\sigma_{2},\nu_{2})\sim VG\left(\sqrt{\sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2}},\frac{\nu_{1}+\nu_{2}}{\nu_{1}\nu_{2}}\right)$, which has additional constraint $\sigma_{1}^{2}\nu_{1}=\sigma_{2}^{2}\nu_{2}$. Here, we slightly diverge from this additional condition and use the first one, which results an approx. exact density. Therefore, final result is  $\frac{1}{2}[X_{1}-X_{2}]+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}[Y_{1}-Y_{2}] \sim VG(\sigma=2, \nu=1)$.
$$\begin{equation}
f_{X}\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{4\sqrt{\pi}}K_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(4\sqrt{2}|x|\right),
\end{equation}$$
After we check this result with MC simulation, we see that the result is fairly successful to have a closed form density and MC simulation is caught almost perfectly by both pdf and cdf. [image] [image]

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: What can be said about the error bounds?

Comment: From graph above which uses 10000 discrete points, the empirical error bound of analytical approximate cdf is [0.009091097,9.511157e-07], mean of absolute differences is 0.001524428. Meaning the maximum and minimum differences between empirical cdf and analytical cdf.