# $\chi^2$-distribution of $(x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4)^2-(-x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^2$ with $x_i \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, chi-squared-distribution

Given are 4 independent normal variables $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i)_{i=1,\ldots,4}$, that are used to define the random variable
$$Z\sim (x_1 - x_2 + x_3 + x_4)^2 - (-x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)^2.\tag{1}$$

Each squared term in eq.(1) is a linear combination of independent normal variables, whence each of those squares has a noncentral $\chi^2(k,M)$-distribution with $k=1$ degree of freedom and noncentrality parameter $M$.  The two linear combinations are also orthogonal, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1&1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 1&1 \end{pmatrix}^T =0$
, whence uncorrelated; and because they are uncorrelated joint random variables, they are *independent* (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/557540/269684)).

Thus the squared linear combinations in eq.(1) can be written as a difference of $\chi^2$-variables
$$Z\sim s \left( \chi^2\left(1,M_1\right)- \chi^2\left(1,M_2\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

with noncentrality parameters $M_1=\dfrac{1}{s}\left(\mu_1-\mu_2+\mu_3+\mu_4\right)^2, M_2=\dfrac{1}{s}\left(-\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3+\mu_4\right)^2$ and total variance $s=\sum_{i=1}^4\sigma^2_i$.

However this approach only works, if all $\sigma_i$ are identical. How to express eq.(1) by $\chi^2$-variables for different $\sigma_i$?

**Graphical examples for PDF**

*All $\sigma_i$ are identical.*

$\sigma=(5,5,5,5), \mu=(2,-11,-1,4)$, black: eq(1), red: eq(2) (both plots almost overlap)

[image]

*All $\sigma_i$ are different.*

$\sigma=(5,4,3,2), \mu=(2,-11,-1,4)$, black: eq(1), red: eq(2)

[image]

Comment: Short answer: $Z$ can be expressed as a quadratic form in four *iid* standard Normal variables.  *Diagonalize it,* reducing the question to a weighted sum of squares of non-central chi-squared variates: you're done.

Comment: Even shorter.  Let $Z_1=4(X_1-X_2)$ and $Z_2=X_3+X_4$.  $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent normals with respective means $4(\mu_1-\mu_2)$ and $\mu_3+\mu_4$ and respective variances $16(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$ and $\sigma_3^2+\sigma_4^2$.  Now $Z=(Z_1/4+Z_2)^2-(-Z_1+Z_2)^2=Z_1 Z_2$.  Now you're just dealing with the product of two independent normals.

Comment: @JimB: Right -- but it's "even shorter" only for this special case.  Generally, a quadratic form will be expressible as a linear combination of noncentral chi-squared variates, but not as a product of Normal variates.

Comment: @whuber  I will amend my answer with that in mind.

Answer (score 6):

This problem is initially written as the difference in the squares of two correlated normals.

$$Z=(X_1-X_2+X_3+X_4)^2-(-X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4)^2$$

where all of the $X_i$ are independent random variables with potentially different means and variances:  $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$.

The request is to re-write $Z$ in terms of the difference in two independent noncentral chisquare random variables times some constant:

$$Z=s(W_1-W_2)$$

where $W_i\sim \chi^2(1,m_i)$.  To do so we do something similar to the idea presented in @whuber 's comment:  The characteristic functions are found for both characterizations of $Z$ and then we equate all of the coefficients for the characteristic function argument $t$.

To have a less cluttered expression for

$$Z=(X_1-X_2+X_3+X_4)^2-(-X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4)^2$$

we first re-write $Z$ as follows:

$$Z=(Z_{12}+Z_{34})^2 - (-Z_{12}+Z_{34})^2$$

where $Z_{12}=X_1-X_2$ and $Z_{34}=X_3+X_4$.  $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{34}$ are independent normals with respective means and variances $\mu_{12}=\mu_1-\mu_2$, $\mu_{34}=\mu_3+\mu_4$, $\sigma_{12}^2=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$, and $\sigma_{34}^2=\sigma_3^2+\sigma_4^2$.

Written this way the characteristic function of $Z$ is found with

```
Format[μ[i_]]:=Subscript[μ,i]
Format[σ[i_]]:=Subscript[σ,i]
dist = TransformedDistribution[(z[12] + z[34])^2 - (-z[12] + z[34])^2,
    {z[12] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[12], σ[12]],
     z[34] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[34], σ[34]]}];
cf = CharacteristicFunction[dist, t]
```

$$\frac{e^ {-\frac{4 t \left(-i \mu _{12} \mu _{34}+2 \mu _{34}^2 \sigma _{12}^2 t+2 \mu _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2 t\right)}{16 \sigma _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2 t^2+1}}}{\sqrt{16 \sigma _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2 t^2+1}}=\frac{e^{\frac{-t^2 \left(8 \mu _{34}^2 \sigma _{12}^2+8 \mu _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2\right)+i 4 \mu _{12} \mu _{34} t}{16 \sigma _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2 t^2+1}}}{\sqrt{16 \sigma _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2 t^2+1}}$$

The characteristic function for the alternate formulation is found with the following:

```
Format[m[i_]]:=Subscript[m,i]
dist2 = TransformedDistribution[s (w[1] - w[2]),
   {w[1] \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m[1]],
    w[2] \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m[2]]}];
cf2 = CharacteristicFunction[dist2, t];
```

$$\frac{e^{-s t \left(\frac{m_1}{2 s t+i}+\frac{m_2}{2 s t-i}\right)}}{\sqrt{4 s^2 t^2+1}}=\frac{e^{\frac{-2 \left(m_1+m_2\right) s^2 t^2+i \left(m_1-m_2\right) s t}{4 s^2 t^2+1}}}{\sqrt{4 s^2 t^2+1}}$$

We can find the matching terms of $t$ and $t^2$ in the exponents to determine $m_1$, $m_2$, and $s$.  This means we need to simultaneously solve

$$16 \sigma^2_{12} \sigma^2_{34}=4s^2$$
$$8 \mu^2_{34}\sigma^2_{12}+8\mu^2_{12}\sigma^2_{34}=2s^2(m_1+m_2)$$
$$4\mu_{12}\mu_{34}=s(m_1-m_2)$$

```
sol = Solve[{16 σ[12]^2 σ[34]^2 == 4 s^2, 
  8 μ[34]^2 σ[12]^2 + 8 μ[12]^2 σ[34]^2 == 2 s^2 (m[1] + m[2]), 
  4 μ[12] μ[34] == s (m[1] - m[2])}, {s, m[1], m[2]}]
```

This results in two solutions:

$$s= \pm 2 \sigma _{12} \sigma _{34}$$
$$m_1= \frac{\left(\mu _{34} \sigma _{12}\pm\mu _{12} \sigma _{34}\right){}^2}{2 \sigma _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2}$$
$$m_2= \frac{\left(\mu _{34} \sigma _{12}\mp\mu _{12} \sigma _{34}\right){}^2}{2 \sigma _{12}^2 \sigma _{34}^2}$$

Finally, we can plug in the original parameters:

```
parms = {μ[12] -> μ[1] - μ[2], μ[34] -> μ[3] + μ[4], σ[12] -> Sqrt[σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2],  σ[34] -> Sqrt[σ[3]^2 + σ[4]^2]}
sol = sol //. parms
```

$$s= \pm 2 \sqrt{\sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2} \sqrt{\sigma _3^2+\sigma _4^2}$$
$$m_1= \frac{\left(\left(\mu _2-\mu _1\right) \sqrt{\sigma _3^2+\sigma _4^2}\pm\left(\mu _3+\mu _4\right) \sqrt{\sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2}\right){}^2}{2 \left(\sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2\right) \left(\sigma _3^2+\sigma _4^2\right)}$$
$$m_2= \frac{\left(\left(\mu _1-\mu _2\right) \sqrt{\sigma _3^2+\sigma _4^2}\mp \left(\mu _3+\mu _4\right) \sqrt{\sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2}\right){}^2}{2 \left(\sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2\right) \left(\sigma _3^2+\sigma _4^2\right)}$$

As a check consider one of the given examples.

```
parms = {μ[1] -> 2, μ[2] -> -11, μ[3] -> -1, μ[4] -> 4, σ[1] -> 5,
  σ[2] -> 4, σ[3] -> 3, σ[4] -> 2};
parms1 = {μ[12] -> μ[1] - μ[2], μ[34] -> μ[3] + μ[4], σ[12] -> Sqrt[σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2],
  σ[34] -> Sqrt[σ[3]^2 + σ[4]^2]};
z1 = RandomVariate[dist /. parms1 /. parms, 1000000];

dist2 = TransformedDistribution[
  s (w[1] - w[2]) /. sol[[2]] /. parms1 /. parms, 
  {w[1] \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m[1]], 
   w[2] \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m[2]]} /. sol[[2]] /. parms1 /. parms];
z2 = RandomVariate[dist2 /. parms, 1000000];

Histogram[z1, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"]
```

[image: Histogram of samples from original distribution]

```
Histogram[z2, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"]
```

[image: Histogram of transformed distribution]

We can also check on the corresponding sample means and variances:

```
{Mean[#], Variance[#]} & /@ {z1, z2}
(* {{156.019, 49649.8}, {156.27, 49587.}} *)
```

The pdf can also be easily found numerically using the characteristic function for specified values of the parameters.

**Answer to a comment below:**

It was asked to find the distribution and characteristic function of a more complicated random variable:

$$X=(z_5-z_3)(z_2-z_4)-(z_1-z_3)(z_6-z_4)$$

Rather than directly using that definition, it appears that *Mathematica* needs a little help.

First determine the multivariate normal distribution of the 4 differences in normal random variables.

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[{z[5] - z[3], z[2] - z[4], z[1] - z[3], z[6] - z[4]},
  {z[1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[1], σ[1]], 
   z[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[2], σ[2]], 
   z[3] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[3], σ[3]], 
   z[4] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[4], σ[4]], 
   z[5] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[5], σ[5]], 
   z[6] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[6], σ[6]]}]

(*  MultinormalDistribution[{-μ[3] + μ[5], μ[2] - μ[4], μ[1] - μ[3], -μ[4] + μ[6]}, 
  {{σ[3]^2 + σ[5]^2, 0,               σ[3]^2,           0}, 
   {0,               σ[2]^2 + σ[4]^2, 0,                σ[4]^2}, 
   {σ[3]^2,          0,               σ[1]^2 + σ[3]^2,  0}, 
   {0,               σ[4]^2,          0,                σ[4]^2 + σ[6]^2}}]*)
```

Now set up rules such that the parameters in the above distribution each have a single symbol.  This seems to be necessary for *Mathematica* to complete in a reasonable amount of time.

```
parms1 = {-μ[3] + μ[5] -> μ1, μ[2] - μ[4] -> μ2, μ[1] - μ[3] -> μ3, -μ[4] + μ[6] -> μ4,
  σ[3]^2 + σ[5]^2 -> v1, σ[2]^2 + σ[4]^2 -> v2, σ[1]^2 + σ[3]^2 -> v3, 
  σ[4]^2 + σ[6]^2 -> v4, σ[3]^2 -> v5, σ[4]^2 -> v6};

(* Find distribution and characteristic function of the simplified difference 
   of the products of normally distributed random variables *)
dist2 = TransformedDistribution[x[1] x[2] - x[3] x[4],
  {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]} \[Distributed] dist] /.parms1;
AbsoluteTiming[cf = CharacteristicFunction[dist2, t]]
```

The result is messy and takes about 4 minutes to run.  Now replace with the original parameters:

```
parms2 = parms1 /. {Rule[a_, b_] -> Rule[b, a]}
cf = cf /. parms2
```

That result is even messier so I won't show it here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  An earlier version used $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ but in an attempt to make things clearer, I switched those to $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{34}$ but obviously didn't make all of the changes in the text.  I'm in the process of simplifying my answer and should have that done later today.

Comment: What case is taking a long time?  The characteristic functions `cf` and `cf2` take 13 seconds and 0.03 seconds, respectively.

Comment: If one rewrites that random variable as$ x_1 x_2-x_3 x_4$ where $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ has multiivariate normal distribution, then the characteristic functions takes about 6 minutes to complete.  Sometimes *Mathematica* needs a little help.  (In other words, $x_1=z_5-x_3$, $x_2=z_2-z_4$, etc.)

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes, $x_1=z_5-x_3$ should be $x_1=z_5-z_3$.

Comment: I've given you all of the information necessary.  I hope it works out.

Comment: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ as stated has a multivariate normal distribution.  I gave the definitions of $x_1$ and $x_2$ but figured you could see that $x_3=z_1-z_3$ and $x_4=z_6-z_4$.  *Mathematica* can handle this as there are just 4 random variables rather than 6.

Comment: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ has a multivariate normal distribution with each element ($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$) having a univariate normal distribution.

Comment: Don't know what happened there.  It is now fixed.

Comment: I'm not doing well with my cutting-and-pasting.  I left off the `/.parms1` from the definition of `dist2`.  With that fix I, again, get the result in 4 minutes on my older PC and 6 minutes on my laptop.  I'll enter the edit a bit later today.  You might want to add in that additional question in your original post or start a new post.

Comment: The assignments ```σ[3]^2 -> v5, σ[4]^2 -> v6``` in ```parms1``` seem to be either wrong, incomplete or superficial or I do not understand its meaning.

Comment: Why do you say that?  As you've seen I do make mistakes but I need something more than a feeling as to why those assignments are wrong.  Those ($\sigma_3^2$ and $\sigma_4^2$ are terms in the off-diagonal of the covariance matrix.  The whole point of  the reassignment using `parms1` was to make the structure as simple as possible for *Mathematica*.  Possibly those weren't necessary but I wasn't going to try all combinations.  Those re-assignments minimized the number of symbols and operations in the covariance matrix.

Comment: Sorry, you did find another error.  I cut-and-pasted incorrectly again.  ` σ[2]^2 + σ[4]^2 -> v3` should be  `σ[2]^2 + σ[4]^2 -> v2`.

Answer (score 3):

For this special case the random variable $Z$ can be simplified to the product of two independent normals:

Let $Z_1=4(X_1-X_2)$ and $Z_2=X_3+X_4$.  $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent normals with respective means $4(\mu_1-\mu_2)$ and $\mu_3+\mu_4$ and respective variances $16(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$ and $\sigma_3^2+\sigma_4^2$.  Now

$$Z=(Z_1/4+Z_2)^2-(-Z_1/4+Z_2)^2=Z_1 Z_2$$

Finding moments of $Z$ should be straightforwared.  To plot the pdf of $Z$ using *Mathematica* (which your profile says you have access), one can execute the following:

```
(* Numerical estimate of the pdf of Z *)
pdf[z_?NumericQ, μ1_?NumericQ, σ1_?NumericQ, μ2_?NumericQ, σ2_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], x] PDF[NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], z/x]/Abs[x],
 {x, -∞, ∞}]

(* Parameters from your example *)
σz1 = Sqrt[16 (25 + 16)]
σz2 = Sqrt[9 + 4]
μz1 = 4 (2 - (-11))
μz2 = -1 + 4

(* Plot of density *)
Plot[pdf[z, μz1, σz1, μz2, σz2], {z, -400, 1000}]
```

[image: PDF of Z using OP's example parameters]

**Expressing Z as a linear combination of two independent noncentral
chisquare rv's**

Define the distribution of the linear combination.

$$Z=a_1\chi^2(1,m_1)+a_2\chi^2(1,m_2)$$

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[a1 y1 + a2 y2,
   {y1 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m1], 
    y2 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m2]}];
```

Define the distribution of Z expressed as the product of two
independent normal rv's.

```
distz1z2 = TransformedDistribution[z1 z2,
  {z1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μz1, σz1], 
   z2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μz2, σz2]}];
```

If we can characterize $Z$ as a linear combination of two
independent noncentral $\chi^2$ rv's which has 4 parameters, then
the first 4 moments need to match with that of the characterization
of $Z$ as the product of two independent normals.

```
sol = Solve[{Mean[distz1z2] == Mean[dist], 
     Variance[distz1z2] == Variance[dist],
     Moment[distz1z2, 3] == Moment[dist, 3], 
     Moment[distz1z2, 4] == Moment[dist, 4]},
    {a1, a2, m1, m2}][[1]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Solution to parameters of linear combination]

From above we know that

```
parms2 = {σz1 -> Sqrt[16 (σ1^2 + σ2^2)], σz2 -> Sqrt[σ3^2 + σ4^2], 
  μz1 -> 4 (μ1 - μ2), μz2 -> μ3 + μ4};
```

So in terms of the original parameters the parameters of the
linear combination of independent noncentral chisquare rv's are

```
sol /. parms2
```

[image: Solution in terms of original parameters]

As a minimal check, consider your example.

```
parms = {μ1 -> 2, μ2 -> -11, μ3 -> -1, μ4 -> 4, σ1 -> 5, σ2 -> 4, σ3 -> 3, σ4 -> 2};
zA = RandomVariate[distz1z2 /. sol /. parms2 /. parms, 1000000];
zB = RandomVariate[dist /. sol /. parms2 /. parms, 1000000];
Histogram[zA, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", PlotRange -> {{-700, 1300}, {0, 0.003}}]
```

[image: Histogram of density for product of two independent normals]

```
Histogram[zB, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", PlotRange -> {{-700, 1300}, {0, 0.003}}]
```

[image: Histogram of density for linear combination of two noncentral chisquare random variables]

Comment: Can the answer solely be expressed by $\chi^2$ variables as desired by the OP?

Comment: I know that's what you asked for but what I've presented is an approach to obtain the exact distribution.  However, I'll take a look at if the distribution of $Z$ can be expressed as a linear combination of two independent noncentral $\chi^2$ variables.  If so, that will just be equivalent to characterizing the distribution of $Z$ as the product of two independent normals.

Comment: How to solve the problem without Mathematica? For this case, accidentially, after 5 minutes of calculation, Mathematica returns a result. But we do not learn anything about the steps and therefore do not know the limit of the method.

Comment: “accidentally” ? Ha, ha. You have the answer.  Like is too short for me to spend time on such things. And get a faster computer.

Comment: How can Mathematica solve this if we instead of the product distribution of 2 normals use the original form (eq.1) as input for the code.

Comment: Can you help me understand why that would be necessary?  Why not $Z=(x_1-x_2 + x_3)^2-(-x_1+x_2+x_3)^2$?  Without the rationale for doing so, it appears that you want to make things more complicated than necessary. Unless...there's a different problem that you want to solve that does require something more complicated.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how Mathematica can solve it for your difference of squared normals.

Comment: After 30h on a modern CPU Mathematica is still calculating.

Comment: If you could show the code that is taking so long, that would be helpful.

Comment: dist = TransformedDistribution[
   a1 y1 + a2 y2, {y1 \[Distributed] 
     NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m1], 
    y2 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[1, m2]}];
distz1z2 = 
  TransformedDistribution[(z1 - z2 + z3)^2 - (-z1 + z2 + 
      z3)^2, {z1 \[Distributed] 
     NormalDistribution[\[Mu]z1, \[Sigma]z1], 
    z2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu]z2, \[Sigma]z2], 
    z3 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu]z3, \[Sigma]z3]}];

Comment: sol = Solve[{Mean[distz1z2] == Mean[dist], 
     Variance[distz1z2] == Variance[dist], 
     Moment[distz1z2, 3] == Moment[dist, 3], 
     Moment[distz1z2, 4] == Moment[dist, 4]}, {a1, a2, m1, m2}][[1]] //
   FullSimplify

Comment: Hmmm.  I now wonder if it is because $a_1=-a_2$ and therefore trying to fit 4 parameters when only 3 are needed is the problem.  Fitting `a y1 - a y2` and using just the first 3 moments works almost instantly even if using `(z1 - z2 + z3 + z4)^2 - (-z1 + z2 + z3 + z4)^2`.

Comment: The case $a1=-a2$ is assumed in the OP however fails. Therefore it is not known beforehand that $a1=-a2$.

Comment: That case doesn't fail for me.  I do agree that it was not known beforehand that $a_1=-a_2$.  But that happens sometimes when a model is unknowingly overparameterized.

Comment: As a check...if you plug in any 8 numbers for $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\mu_3$, $\mu_4$, $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\sigma_3$, and $\sigma_4$ (with the standard deviations all being positive), you'll find that you can get the exact same characteristic function for $s(\chi^2(1,m_1)-\chi^2(1,m_2)$ with only the 3 parameters $s$, $m_1$, and $m_2$.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer only explains why the approach fails but does not say how to get the expected result.*

Set $$y_i\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\dfrac{\mu_i}{\sigma_i},1\right)$$ and write
$$Z\sim(\sigma_1 y_1-\sigma_2 y_2+\sigma_3 y_3+\sigma_4 y_4)^2-(-\sigma_1 y_1+ \sigma_2 y_2+\sigma_3 y_3+\sigma_4 y_4)^2.$$ You see that the linear combinations are not orthogonal but dependent. They are independent only for the special case $\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2=\sigma^2_3+\sigma^2_4$.