# Probability of X greater than Y with different types of random variable

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution, probability-inequalities, exponential-distribution

My problem is the following: I have 2 random variables $X \sim Gamma(2,\mu_2)$ and $Y \sim Exp(\mu_1)$. I have to compute $P(X > Y)$.

How can I do that ? Thank you

Comment: Does this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/264861/930

Comment: It's too complicated

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Well, it started with an homework exercise, but this is all about my curiosity, because in my opinion is a great thing trying to solve problems in different ways.