# What is the expectation of $\log(1+aX)$ where $X$ has an $F$ distribution?

Tags: distributions, expected-value

The random variable $Y$ is defined by $Y=\log(1+aX)$ where $X$ has an $F(m,m)$ distribution and $a$ is a non-negative constant.  What is the expectation of $Y$?

Comment: It would be much simpler to note that if $X \sim F(2,2)$, then its pdf is $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

Comment: X has an F(m,m) distribution.not F(2,2)

Comment: I can't find the formula for this integral,when $X$ has an $F(m,m)$ distribution

Comment: For arbitrary degrees of freedom $a$ and $b,$ there is a relatively simple formula in terms of $\csc,$ $\Gamma$, and the logarithmic derivative of $\Gamma$ (*aka* $\psi,$ the "polygamma" function). It becomes indeterminate whenever either $2a$ or $2b$ is an integer, but can be evaluated with one or two applications of L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ be two independent $\chi^2_m$ random variables. We can write $F = X/Y \sim F_{m,m}.$ Note: you call my $F$ by $X$.

Notice that
$$
E\left[\log(1 + aF)\right] =  E\left[\log\left(\frac{aX + Y}{Y}\right)\right] = E[\log(aX + Y)] - E[\log(Y)].
$$
This might be easier to evaluate. $E[\log(Y)]$ has a [formula you can look up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Logarithmic_expectation_and_variance).

If $a=1$, you can use the same formula for the other part. If not, then general linear combinations of Gamma random variables have a lesser-known distribution (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/generic-sum-of-gamma-random-variables) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/the-distribution-of-the-linear-combination-of-gamma-random-variables)). Perhaps there is some result one can dig up about expectations of the logarithm of these types of random variables. Or we could try integration.

Comment: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/generic-sum-of-gamma-random-variables) can't find the closed-form solution .It's an approximation.[this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/the-distribution-of-the-linear-combination-of-gamma-random-variables) The PDF form in this one cannot be integrated.